# Alignment issues on personal Activity page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

When going to the Questions and Bookmarks tabs on a user's profile's Activity page, the questions and their meta-data are not properly aligned:

[image]
<sup>Colours due to Dark Reader plugin</sup>

Of course, this is definitely not a big issue, but I thought I'd mention it all the same.

Comment: I guess the misalignment is caused by varying text lengths (left to right), arguably this is a good design choice because otherwise instead of having independent lines of floating divs you'd end up with a table.

Comment: @bad_coder I realize, but the main Stack Exchange pages use the exact same combination of questions and their metadata (excepting the bookmarks amount), and are perfectly aligned.

Comment: Yes that is true, the main reason being views, votes, and nº of answers are vertically grouped in the main page, while they're side-by-side in the user page.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, thank you. I searched for a while, but wasn't able to find anything. I thought someone else ought to have brought it up..

Comment: Great, thanks for the very helpful downvote on a question that's been closed for almost as long as it has been here. [Be more constructive with your feedback](https://youtu.be/sOgC8qp_I2Y?t=126).

Comment: You get a +1...

Comment: @bad_coder Aaaww <3