# Alignment issue of tags on Question Review page

Tags: bug, tags, design

When writing [my last question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360659/alignment-issues-on-personal-activity-page), I noticed another alignment problem, this time with the tags on the Question Review page:

[image]

Again a tiny problem, but probably worth mentioning.

When reviewing this question, the problem did not reoccur:

[image]

So maybe it's a bug with the bug tag :)

Comment: If I understand this right you are mentioning the gap between the tag `bug` and `design` in the first picture? I think this happens if you remove a tag that was in the middle of the two in order to give a visual hint that 1 tag was removed.

Comment: @bad_coder Oh, that could actually be it. I'll try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Here is my reproduction of the scenario:

[image]

It's just a simple indication as to where the tag you just deleted *(probably by accident)* was before it got deleted. As demonstrated in the gif, clicking to the end of the tags removes the gap.